# CKEditor prevents framework's and native events propagation

Tags: ckeditor, angularjs-model

I am having an angular directive that is compiled and inserted into CKEditor. Furthermore i have a widget plugin that upcasts those directives to widgets and allows few of their fields for editing. In those fields there is `<input>` bound to a model that should be displayed in and out of the editor. Exploring the DOM I see that angular has added its classes for binding, but after attaching a watcher to the model, it turns out that no event is fired when somebody is writing inside the `<input>`.

Is CKEditor preventing/hiding those events?
Thank you in advance!